# Returning a DataFrama with nlargest values based on a particular column

Tags: pandas

This is my sample DataFrame:

```
inputArr = [['A', 0, 6],
 ['A', 1, 57],
 ['A', 2, 81],
 ['A', 3, 9],
 ['A', 4, 87],
 ['B', 0, 24],
 ['B', 1, 30],
 ['B', 2, 96],
 ['B', 3, 54],
 ['B', 4, 81],
 ['C', 0, 6],
 ['C', 1, 6],
 ['C', 2, 6],
 ['C', 3, 93],
 ['C', 4, 99],
 ['D', 0, 0],
 ['D', 1, 90],
 ['D', 2, 6],
 ['D', 3, 87],
 ['D', 4, 75],
 ['E', 0, 93],
 ['E', 1, 60],
 ['E', 2, 63],
 ['E', 3, 48],
 ['E', 4, 36]]

trialPD = pd.DataFrame(inputArr, columns = ["Name", "rating", "num_items"])
```

Now, I want to select rows from trialPD where the rating is in top 3 for a particular name. I tried `trialPD.groupby("Name")["rating"].nlargest(3)` but that doesn't seem to be returning the last column (`"num_items"`) at all. is there a way to get the index where the rows match top 3 within a particular grouping?
P.S: This is my first question on StackExchange, so do tell me if I am doing anything wrong. BTW, I found the nlargest solution also on this same forum so thank you all for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of tuples: top 3 rows of each group (group_name,index):

`list(df.groupby('Name')['Ratings'].nlargest(3).index)`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just Add Pandas DataFrame Around It]

Just Add Pandas DataFrame Around It

```
pd.DataFrame(df_xls.groupby(['Category','Sub-Category'])['Sales'].sum().groupby(['Category']).nlargest(2))
```